# How to safety forward arguments to closure in object in typescript

Tags: typescript

following code works fine, but I failed try to remove `@ts-ignore`.

```js
const actions = {
  a: (x: number): number => x,
  b: (x: number, y: string) => x,
  c: (x: number, y: string) => y,
};

interface Action<K extends keyof typeof actions> {
  type: K;
  payload: ReturnType<typeof actions[K]>;
}

function action<K extends keyof typeof actions, Args extends Parameters<typeof actions[K]>>(
  type: K,
  ...args: Args
): Action<K> {
  return {
    type,
    // FIXME: remove @ts-ignore.
    // @ts-ignore
    payload: actions[type](...args),
  };
}

const a: Action<'a'> = { type: 'a', payload: 1 };
const b: { type: 'b'; payload: number } = action('b', 42, 'hello');
const c: { type: 'c'; payload: string } = action('c', 42, 'hello');
```